# SMS sharing not working in ios7 in html web app

Tags: html, mobile, web-applications, ios7

I am developing for iphone web apps.I have been working on SMS sharing.Code for sharing in android is as follows

```
<a class="sprite-image mobile-sms-icon" target="_blank" href="sms:?body=http%3A%2F%2F54.235.73.20%3A8080%2FZinappView%2Fread.htm%3Fp%3Ddb28c2e3f06f4a68a80fac68c23ee5eb">
```

and for iphone is as follows

```
<a class="sprite-image mobile-sms-icon" target="_blank" href="sms:;body=http%3A%2F%2F54.235.73.20%3A8080%2FZinappView%2Fread.htm%3Fp%3Ddb28c2e3f06f4a68a80fac68c23ee5eb">
```

Both of above are working properly.But the problem is that for iphone having ios7,sms sharing is not working.How can I resolve this issue?